# Open source javascript editor / designer, draggable boxes of fonts & images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, wysiwyg

I need to build a visual designer image or card designer that lets you add text boxes of text (multiple fonts), or images, drag them around, and resize them.

This seems rather simple but I would yet think common - but so far I haven't found anything I could use as a basis for this.

What I'm looking for is something like Keynote but super basic.

I've looked at:

- remark.js: presentation only
- reveal.js: Pretty close, but only the presentation engine is open source. The visual editor is a closed source service.
- mxgraph / jgraph: designed for directed graphs or flowchart
- gojs: designed for directed graphs or flowchart
- contentbuilder: its a layout engine for a page with stacked layout modules, I need something that authors a card

Of course also staple javasript editors like ACE, CK and TinyMCE but they solve the font editing / font selection problem, but not the drag & drop boxes & layout issue.

What I'm trying to build is something you might use on tinyprints.com or minted when you design your card, or canva.com.

But my needs are really basic - so I'm thinking that possibly the reason there isn't a library for this is that its pretty easy to build it? Anyway, would love some input.

Comment: Added an answer but also wondering if you found anything else that fit your need(s).

Answer (score 0):

It's less of a layout editor/designer but [Fabric JS](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink) has a lot of the features you are looking for (multiple fonts, dragging images around and resizing). It's Canvas-based but can export to JSON if you need to transfer to a non-raster format. Might be adaptable if this is still a need.